# Jquery add class to existing item on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/47apf/12/

Very simply, I'm trying to hide the button for those users who have javascript enabled. I am using this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.trigger').addClass.attr('hidden');
  $('#candidate_filter').change(function() {
    this.submit();
  });
});
```

I am new to jquery, is there any reason why this isn't working? It says in the log "undefined is not a function".

Comment: You might need to be much more attentive with your syntax else you'll get stuck at almost every line of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use,

```
  $('.trigger').addClass('hidden');
```

You are not utilizing the syntax properly. Read here to know more about [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/47apf/14/)